# Isolate part of string

Tags: regex

I need to isolate the "_Back-80x80.png" portion of the following URL, and replace it using Javascript. I understand how to replace it, just need help isolating the SKU portion with regex. The only constant will be that its comes after `wp-content/uploads/` and before the last `/` in the string.

```
/wp-content/uploads/SKU_Back-80x80.png
```

I've captured everything after `wp-content/uploads/`, just can't figure out how to ignore everything before the SKU.

```
/\/wp-content\/uploads\/.*/g
```

Comment: Use `/\/wp-content\/uploads\/([^_]+)/`

Comment: That ignores `_Back-80x80.png` but the `/wp-content/uploads/` portion is still included

Comment: It does not matter if wp is included or not, the capture group holds the value you need. What is the programming language? What do you mean by *That ignores `_Back-80x80.png`*? You say you only want to get all up to the `_`, you say you only need `SKU`, don't you? If not, and you need to get all to the end of the string, use `s.replace(/(\/wp-content\/uploads\/)[^\/]*/g, "$1" + newVar)`.

Comment: what's the programming language ?

Comment: Javascript. Thought it over and it should work. I essentially need to update the SKU portion of the URL with a string saved in a variable, but I can just include `/wp-content/uploads/` in that. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, so `s.replace(/(\/wp-content\/uploads\/)[^\/]*/g, "$1" + newVar)`? Please update the question with actual requirements.

Comment: Yeah, that should do it. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to update the whole part after `/wp-content/uploads/` to the next `/` or end of string.

Use

```
s = s.replace(/(\/wp-content\/uploads\/)[^\/]*/g, "$1" + new_value);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/O0Lw6U/1)

**Details**

- `(\/wp-content\/uploads\/)` - Group 1, a literal `/wp-content/uploads/` substring (it is referred to using `$1` replacement backreference from the replacement pattern)
- `[^\/]*` - 0 or more chars other than `/`

If `new_value` may contain `$`, replace it with `new_value.replace(/\$/g, '$$$$')` in the code above (this will escape the dollar symbols correctly).

Answer (score 1):

if you want to extract anything between `/` and `_` like `SKU` here is a method:

```js
const regex = /\/\w*\_/g

const text = "/wp-content/uploads/SKU_Back-80x80.png"

console.log(text.match(regex)[0].substring(1, (text.match(regex)[0].length - 1)))
```

Comment: For this solution, how would you also exclude the `/` and `_`?

Comment: you re using javascript right ? i already did that with `substring`

Comment: Ah, apologies, didn't consider that part of your answer. Thanks.